# Enabling CORS Python in Google Cloud Platform Function

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, cors, flask-cors

I've followed a few Medium articles as well as Google's own tutorials and still can't get CORS enabled using flask on this function :(

What code am I missing to enable CORS? I want wildcard of * as I want all services/ domains to be able to access this and other functions.

I've heard GCP does not work well with @app. Why, I am not so sure.

Note I have been successful with testing outputs directly on my browser's url bar as well as Triggering a JSON test within GCP itself.

My intended use is for GET requests only.

```
from flask import Flask
import re

def hello_method(request):
    from flask import abort

    if request.method == 'GET':
        
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }

        request_json = request.get_json()
        pattern = re.compile("([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)")
        
        if request.args and 'x' and 'y' in request.args:
            x_str = request.args.get('x')
            y_str = request.args.get('y')

            if not (pattern.match(x_str)):
                rtn = "{\"error\":true,\"string\":" + "NaN" + "*" + y_str + "=" + "NaN" + ",\"answer\":" + "NaN" +"}"
                return (rtn, 204, headers)
            if not (pattern.match(y_str)):
                rtn = "{\"error\":true,\"string\":" + x_str + "*" + "NaN" + "=" + "NaN" + ",\"answer\":" + "NaN" +"}"
                return (rtn, 204, headers)

            x = float(x_str)
            y = float(y_str)
            print("Args X: " + str(x))
            print("Args Y: " + str(y))
            ans = x * y
            print("Args Answer: " + str(ans))
            rtn = "{\"error\":false,\"string\":" + str(x) + "*" + str(y) + "=" + str(ans) + ",\"answer\":" + str(ans) +"}"
            return (rtn, 204, headers)
        elif request_json and 'x' and 'y' in request_json:
            x_str = request.args.get('x')
            y_str = request.args.get('y')

            if not (pattern.match(x_str)):
                rtn = "{\"error\":true,\"string\":" + "NaN" + "*" + y_str + "=" + "NaN" + ",\"answer\":" + "NaN" +"}"
                return (rtn, 204, headers)
            if not (pattern.match(y_str)):
                rtn = "{\"error\":true,\"string\":" + x_str + "*" + "NaN" + "=" + "NaN" + ",\"answer\":" + "NaN" +"}"
                return (rtn, 204, headers)

            print("JSON: ", request_json)
            x = float(request_json['x'])
            y = float(request_json['y'])
            print("JSON X: ", str(x)) 
            print("JSON Y: ", str(y))
            ans = x * y
            print("JSON Answer 2: " + str(ans))
            rtn = "{\"error\":false,\"string\":" + str(x) + "*" + str(y) + "=" + str(ans) + ",\"answer\":" + str(ans) +"}"
            return (rtn, 204, headers)
        else:
            return f"Please pass 2 variables x and y as http"

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        return abort(403)
    else:
        return abort(405)
```

I seem to be aware of the theory of CORS but my practice isn't yet strong enough and GCP seemingly works with flask-cors differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use Flask. Each function is intended to be a single action and Cloud Functions is already responsible of request routing and the framework handling.

As for the CORS issue there are examples available in the Cloud Functions [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#handling_cors_requests) on how to handle CORS.

---

In the updated code you're denying the PUT requests and returning the CORS headers on GET method instead of in OPTIONS method. This is not what the documentation linked above does, please check it carefully. The schema of the Cloud Function should be like:

```
def the_function(request):
    # Return CORS headers on OPTIONS request.
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS':
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age': '3600'
        }
        return ('', 204, headers)
    
    # If the request is GET then handle it normally
    if request.method == 'GET':
        x = request.args('x')
        y = request.args('x')
        result = int(x) * int(y)
        headers = {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
        return (result, 200, headers)
     else:
        # If the request is not GET or OPTIONS, deny.
        return '', 400
```

---

I understand that you only want to allow GET requests to the function. However, the OPTIONS HTTP method must be allowed for CORS to work properly. When a webpage requests content to another domain the browser might send a [preflight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request) request to the target domain (Cloud Function in this case) asking whether the actual GET/POST/etc.. request will be allowed. In order to accomplish this an OPTIONS request is sent to the server and the server must respond acknowledging the allowed HTTP methods. Therefore, for the function to work as expected it must:

1. Return the `Access-Control-Allow-XXX` headers on OPTIONS method.
2. Accept whatever other method returns the actual response, GET in this case.

Comment: Hi, ok! Will try following these instructions now then :). Will keep this updated

Comment: I tried the following wrap around if else statement (appended above). It functions in the URL but I still get a CORS error when testing it on different domains :(

Comment: Updated: including manual CORS return headers and amended return statements. GCP has deployed this ok.

Comment: So my intended use for this function is only for GET requests, hence denying PUSH or OPTIONS. Would you be kind as to show me a solution of my above code working for only GET requests please? This has been insightful for me

Comment: I've tried your code with adding a "response = " (for testing) with no luck, renaming my function header call. I placed () around the bottom return variables. Did you try this in GCP? Thank you for your correspondence.

Comment: @StressedBoi I just updated the code with a minimal working example. Make sure your code follows the same structure .

Comment: I have since changed your above Solution (as there were a few teething problems). And I have a URL Trigger response :) I am going to change up the "actual" response part to see if CORS part work ok! Will keep this updated. Thanks for your efforts so far :)

Comment: Trigger URL: "XXX.cloudfunctions.net/the_function?x=7&y=8" Response: {"error":false,"string":7.0X7.0=ans,"answer":49.0}

Comment: Triggering from a different domain. Google Chrome > Inspect Element > Console: "VM91:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position 27
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.Equals.xhttp.onreadystatechange " Note: token "X" is the multiply sign. It breaks here :(

Comment: Adding "JSON.stringify(this.response)" inside JSON.parse(<in here>) spits to my screen "undefined"

Comment: Invoking "parseInt();" on json output's ".answer" produces NaN. "answer" comes from my Python return statement.

Comment: @StressedBoi All the errors mentioned come from **your modifications** to the sample I shared and are not directly related to CORS. The code as it is doesn't have CORS issues and follows Cloud Function documented practices. Please understand I'm not going to rewrite the whole function for you. In case you need assistance to debug syntax/python library error I'd suggest opening a separate question.

Comment: Hi, Sorry! Understand that, was just keeping this thread updated. I've nearly got it, as it's now a non-CORS related issue I'm having in Javascript. Thanks for your. Wouldn't have made it this far otherwise.